# Get username value of logged in user in Wicket

Tags: wicket

How do I get the username of the currently logged in user in a wicket java file? I would imagine it would be something simple like `getSession().getUsername()` but such a method doesn't exist.

Comment: How do you authenticate users?

Comment: I use the default wicket auth/roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your session stores the user, and make a getter for it. Easiest is to extend the `AuthenticatedWebSession`, override the `authenticate` method to store the user on succesful authentication by `super.authenticate()`

Answer (score 2):

How you implement security is up to you.
Depends on what you use.

- Spring? Try Spring Security (former ACEGI). I don't like that.
- JBoss AS? Try [PicketBox](http://www.jboss.org/picketbox). Or Java EE based security.
- Wicket world offers [Wicket Auth/Roles](http://wicket.apache.org/learn/projects/authroles.html), which I use.

It's not for a single code snippet as it's multiple files. But check the example: http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/authorization/

Also check [here](https://github.com/jsenko/essc-portal/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/essc/web/security/EsscAuthSession.java).
I've tried several approaches to security, so the app's is a bit mess in this regard, but you should be able to isolate what's really in effect.

Comment: I tried following their example. I added the line `add(new Label("currentUser", new PropertyModel<User>(this, "session.user")));` and got the error: `Caused by: org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: No get method defined for class: class edu.mit.cci.amtprojects.MyAuthenticatedWebSession expression: user`

Comment: That means that Wicket tries to call this.getSession().getUser(). so the getUser() is missing in the session object. Or not public perhaps.